Details on: Flag incidence variety is a projective variety
Let $0 \leq p \leq q \leq n$. Define the flag incidence variety
$$\text{Fl}(p,q,n):=\{(V,W) : V \leq W, V \in \text{G}(p,n), W \in \text{G}(q,n)\}$$
where $\mathrm{G}(i,n)$ is the Grassmannian, i.e. the set of all $i$ dimensional subspaces of $K^n$. I want to show that $\mathrm{Fl}(p,q,n)$ is a (Zariski) closed subset of the projective variety
$$\mathrm{G}(p,n) \times \mathrm{G}(q,n)$$
This can be viewed as a projective variety by using the Plücker embedding for both Grassmannians and then for the product we can use the Segre embedding.
I think I understand the broad idea: Leaving out some steps in between we have that
$$\langle v_1,...,v_p \rangle \leq \langle w_1,...,w_q \rangle$$
if and only if for all $1 \leq i \leq p$ all maximal minors of the matrix with columns $v_i, w_1,...,w_q$ are 0. This condition can be expressed as a condition in homogeneous polynomials which is nice since we would like to express the incidence variety as a subvariety. But now I am stuck at the details of making this condition compatible with the embeddings. How should I continue here?
First Update:
I have seen that the maximal minors of the matrix with coumns $v_i, w_1,...,w_q$ can be expressed as linear combinations of the entries of $v_i$ with the maximal minors of the matrix with columns $w_1,...,w_q$ and these maximal minors are the Plücker coordinates. But the entries in $v_i$ are homogeneous coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ and are not maximal minors of the matrix with columns $v_1,...,v_p$. As such, the polynomial equations that I have found until now are not both in the Plücker coordinates but just for $w_1,...,w_q$.
I tried resolving the issue by looking at the matrix with columns $v_1,...,v_p,w_1,...,w_q$. Then we also have that
$$\langle v_1,...,v_p \rangle \leq \langle w_1,...,w_q \rangle$$
if and only if the matrix has rank $q$ which again means that all the $(q+1) \times (q+1)$ minors have to vanish. But I do not see how these minors are products of the minors of $v_1,...,v_p$ and $w_1,...,w_q$.
Second Update:
I have found that the Cauchy-Binet formular could be helpful. It states generally that for matrices $A$ and $B$ the $k \times k$ minors of $AB$ are sums of products of $k \times k$ minors of $A$ with $k\times k$ minors of $B$. This seems to be very close to what I am searching for. However, it fails to work since the product
$$\begin{pmatrix}v_1^T \\ \vdots \\ v_p^T \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} w_1 & \cdots & w_q \end{pmatrix},$$
which would have as minors sums of products of the minors of $v_1,...,v_p$ and $w_1,...,w_q$, does not tell us anything about the wanted relation
$$\langle v_1,...,v_p \rangle \leq \langle w_1,...,w_q \rangle$$

I wonder if it might be useful to take a look at some special cases.  So, suppose $p=2, q=n-1$ and we restrict to the fiber where $W = \langle e_1, \ldots, e_{n-1}$.  Then I think the condition you would want would be that $v_1 \wedge v_2$ has zero coefficients in $e_i \wedge e_n$ whenever $i < n$.  To see that's sufficient, if $v_1 = v_1' + \lambda e_n$ and $v_2 = v_2' + \mu e_n$, then $v_1 \wedge v_2 = v_1'\wedge v_2' - \lambda v_2'\wedge e_n + \mu v_1'\wedge e_n$, so the condition would give $\lambda v_2' = \mu v_1$, so $\lambda v_2 = \mu v_1$, and linear independence gives $\lambda=\mu=0$.

(Where I was supposing $v_1', v_2' \in W$.)

For more general $W$, I think the more general condition would be that $v_1\wedge v_2\wedge w_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\widehat{w_i}\wedge\cdots w_{n-1} = 0$ for each $i$.  Which now gives a condition obviously in terms of Pl"ucker coordinates for $v$ but not obviously for $w$.

@DanielSchepler I am not quite sure I can follow. I understood the first comment. But then I don't understand how you want to generalize this. E.g. does that $\hat{w_i}$ mean to omit the $w_i$?. And you say in the end that it is not so obvious that this is in the Plücker coordinates of $w$. Do you mean that it is but not so easy to see or do you mean that you are not sure whether this is in the Plücker coordinates in $w$?

Yes, the hat notation is what I've seen used most often for excluding a small number of terms from a product (or tuple, or wedge product in this case, etc.).  And what I meant is that I'm not sure whether it's in the Plücker coordinates wrt $w$.

On a different tack, maybe you could consider the graph of the function $V \to \Lambda^{q+1}(F^n), v \mapsto v \wedge w_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge w_q$, which would give a subspace of $F^n \oplus \Lambda^{q+1}(F^n)$.  If you then take the condition that that subspace is equal to $V \oplus 0$, in terms of Plücker coordinates for $p$-dimensional subspaces of $F^n \oplus \Lambda^{q+1}(F^n)$, then hopefully the coordinates of that could be bihomogeneous polynomials in terms of the Plücker coordinates for $V$ and $W$.

Or to adjust it a tiny bit so independence of basis of $W$ is also obvious, instead use the function $V \otimes \Lambda^q(W) \to \Lambda^{q+1}(F^n), v \otimes (w_1 \wedge \cdots w_q) \mapsto v \wedge w_1 \wedge \cdots w_q$, which still has domain of dimension $p$, but now the graph is contained in $(F^n \otimes \Lambda^q(F^n)) \oplus \Lambda^{q+1}(F^n)$.

@DanielSchepler It is a bit late, so I will investigate that tomorrow. But thank you already for taking some time to think about it.

I will answer my own question since I have found a way to make it work. It is inspired by the function from the comments of Daniel Schepler. Define $\nu:= v_1 \wedge ... \wedge v_p$ and $\omega:=w_1 \wedge ... \wedge w_q$ and then
$$f_\nu: K^n \to \Lambda^{p+1}K^n, u \mapsto u \wedge \nu$$
and similarly one can define this for $\omega$. Now we want to look at the matrix of $f_\nu$. In the standard basis the $i$-th column is $f_\nu(e_i) = e_i \wedge v_1 \wedge ... \wedge v_p$. This wedge product has as coefficients in the standard basis $ e_{i_1} \wedge ... \wedge e_{i_{p+1}}$ maximal minors of the matrix with columns $e_i, v_1,...,v_p$. These minors either do not include the first column $e_i$, then it is a maximal minor of $(v_1 \cdots v_p)$ or these minors include $e_i$. In the latter case one can expand along the column $e_i$. But there is only one entry at the $i$-th position. So this again is (up to sign) a maximal minor of $(v_1 \cdots v_p)$. Thus, the entries of the matrix of $f_\nu$ are Plücker coordinates in $V$. The same holds for $f_\omega$. And now one can look at the map
$$(f_\nu, f_\omega): K^n \to \Lambda^{p+1}K^n \oplus \Lambda^{q+1}K^n, u \mapsto (u \wedge \nu, u \wedge \omega)$$
Now we can formulate (omitting some steps in between) the equivalence of conditions
$$V \leq W \iff \mathrm{rank} (f_\nu, f_\omega) \leq n-q$$
and the right condition is equivalent to all $(n-q+1) \times (n-q+1)$ minors of the matrix of $(f_\nu, f_\omega)$ vanishing. This is a condition in homogeneous polynomials of the entries of $(f_\nu, f_\omega)$ which are the Plücker coordinates which was to be shown.
